# How to convert from unichar to character

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, char

There is better way to convert from unichar to Character?
tried :

```
var unichar = ...
let str = NSString(characters: &unichar, length: 1) as String
let character = Array(str.characters)[0])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert `unichar` -> `UnicodeScalar` -> `Character`:

```
let c = unichar(8364)
if let uc = UnicodeScalar(c) {
    let char = Character(uc)
    print(char) // €
} else {
    print("illegal input")
}
```

Input values in the range `0xD800...0xDFFF`
(high and low surrogates) are not allowed because they do not 
correspond to valid Unicode scalar values.

If it is guaranteed that those input values do not occur then you 
can simplify the conversion to

```
let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(c)!)
```

To replace a possible invalid input value by a default character
(e.g. a question mark), use

```
let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(c) ?? "?")
```

Comment: And is there any way how to do vice versa  `unichar` -> `Character`?

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander: This *is* about unichar to Character conversion. Do you mean how to convert Character to unichar ?

Comment: Oh, yes, I mean Character to unichar, I have only one idea for this moment - `("c" as NSString).character(at: 0)`

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander: `String(c).utf16.first!` would be one option. But note that a Swift `Character` is an “extended grapheme cluster” and can consist of many UTF-16 code units (emojis, flags, ...). In that case `Array(String(c).utf16)` would return all of them.

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander: And in Swift 5 (currently in beta) you can do `c.utf16.first!` directly, without converting the Character to a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class func stringForIcon(_ icon: NSInteger) -> Character {
        return Character(UnicodeScalar(icon)!)
    }
```